# App setting is getting null for multiple WCF Service applications?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have one WCF Service Application (A) which contains app setting inside web.config.

```
<appSettings>    
<add key="A" value="a1"/>
```

& have another WCF Service Application(B) which contains app setting inside web.config.

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="B" value="b1"/>
 </appSettings>
```

And I took the reference of B.dll inside A and calling the B.GetData1() method inside A class.

```
 public string GetData(int value)
 {
   B.Service1 b = new B.Service1();
   b.GetData1(1);

   return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
 }
```

And this is the b.GetData1() method code inside B class.

```
public string GetData1(int value)
{ 
    string s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["B"].ToString();
    return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
}
```

But here I am getting null value for

```
string s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["B"].ToString();
```

How to resolve this issue? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration files are not used in context of dlls but for web applications.
Even though you have web.config associated to Service "B" adding reference of B.dll in service "A" will not make it available for any code that is running in context of service A. Any code in Service A can read configurations only from its own web.config file and will not be able to access any configurations from Service B.
Workaround is you need to add same settings/configurations which are present in service B's web.config to Service A's web.config. So move  `<add key="B" value="b1"/>` to service A's web.config and it should work.

Comment: Hi...Thanks for reply..Is there any way to do it other than copying app settings in to A's web.config ? Why i am asking this is example only , In real case 'B' Service is being called by several applications. I think it is not  a better way to add 'B's app settings inside caller applications ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other better way of doing it other than coping settings. But in real world scenario if you developing your business logic as WCF service then you would want to consume it as service in other applications/wcf services. If its developed as WCF service then you shouldn't consume it by adding dll reference.

Comment: Thank you..Got it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the `<add key="B" value="b1"/>`in the config of Application A for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the app setting you are trying to access (B) in application A's web.config.